# what does this error mean this came while running a nestjs module created

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, nest

this error came after running npm run start:dev
I did not understand what it does mean?

```js
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { User } from "./users.model";



@Injectable
export class UsersService{

users : Array<User>=[]

getUsers(){
return this.users;
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe a typo. You wrote `@Injectable` instead of `@Injectable()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { User } from "./users.model";

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  users: Array<User> = [];

  getUsers() {
    return this.users;
  }
}
```

The decorator needs to be corrected to @Injectable().

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax error**

You have: `@Injectable`

Needed: `@Injectable()`

**Example**:

https://docs.nestjs.com/providers